# Conditionally render a p:dataGrid and its contents

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rendering

I'm trying to conditionally hide or show a `<p:dataGrid>` based on a session bean property. My `<p:dataGrid>` is wrapped in a p:dialog and I thought I could use the p:dialog's closeListener and onCloseUpdate attributes to control the hide/show of the `<p:dataGrid>`.  I'm using a session based bean boolean property in the rendered attribute of the p:dataGrid that gets set to true in my `<p:remoteCommand>`'s `actionListener="#{bookmarklet.loadImages}"` method and then set to false in the `closeListener="#{bookmarklet.close}"`.  It never gets rendered even though the loadImages method gets executed and the boolean property is set to true. Ideally, I would like to render the `<p:dataGrid>`, if the `value="#{bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}"` is empty.  I tried `rendered="#{!empty bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}"` but I get an EL exception.

page:

```
<p:dialog header="#{bundle['bookmarklet.dialog.HEADER']}" widgetVar="scrapeDlg" modal="true" height="450" width="700" draggable="false" resizable="false" closeListener="#{bookmarklet.close}" onCloseUpdate="imageGrid">    
    <h:form id="scrapeFrm">
        <p:commandButton onclick="rcTest()" value="call server"/>
        <h:inputHidden id="scrapeURL" value="http://www.freefoto.com/preview/04-01-70?ffid=04-01-70"/>
        <p:remoteCommand name="rcTest" process="@this,scrapeURL" actionListener="#{bookmarklet.loadImages}" update="imageGrid"/>
        <p:dataGrid id="imageGrid" var="img" value="#{bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}" columns="1" rows="1" paginator="true" effect="true" 
                                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} " 
                                paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                rendered="#{bookmarkletBean.shouldRender}"> 
             <p:column>  
                 <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">  
                     <p:graphicImage value="#{img}" width="100" height="100"/>   
                 </h:panelGrid>  
             </p:column>  
        </p:dataGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

session bean:

```
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class BookmarkletBean extends BaseSessionBean{
    private List<String> imageURLs;
    private boolean shouldRender;
    private String hidden;


    public String getHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }

    public void setHidden(String hidden) {
        this.hidden = hidden;
    }

    public List<String> getImageURLs() {
        return imageURLs;
    }

    public void setImageURLs(List<String> imageURLs) {
        this.imageURLs = imageURLs;
    }

    public boolean isShouldRender() {
        return shouldRender;
    }

    public void setShouldRender(boolean shouldRender) {
        this.shouldRender = shouldRender;
    }
}
```

action class:

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class Bookmarklet extends BaseAction{
    @Inject
    private BookmarkletBean bookmarkletBean;
    @Inject
    private BookmarkletService bookmarkletService;

    public void loadImages(ActionEvent e) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        ExternalContext context = FacesUtils.getExternalContext();
        String scrapeURL = context.getRequestParameterMap().get("scrapeFrm:scrapeURL");
        bookmarkletBean.setImageURLs(bookmarkletService.scrape(scrapeURL));
        bookmarkletBean.setShouldRender(true);
    }

    public void close(CloseEvent e){
        bookmarkletBean.setShouldRender(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you initially set a components rendered value to false, it does not exist on the page.  When update is called on imageGrid there is no component found to update.

What you'll have to do is wrap the `<p:dataGrid>` in an `<p:ouputPanel>` and update the `<p:outputPanel>` instead of your `<p:dataGrid>`.

```
<h:form id="scrapeFrm">
    <p:commandButton onclick="rcTest()" value="call server"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="scrapeURL" value="url"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="rcTest" update="imageGrid" process="@this,scrapeURL" actionListener="#{bookmarklet.loadImages}" />
    <p:outputPanel id="imageGrid">
        <p:dataGrid var="img" rendered="#{bookmarkletBean.shouldRender} value="#{bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}""> 
            ...
        </p:dataGrid>
     </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: yeah I have <p:commandButton value="open dialog" onclick="scrapeDlg.show();" type="button"/>

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I was able to get it to conditionally render using your suggestion above, but how would I hide the panel again?  I tried using the dialog's closeListener="#{bookmarklet.close}" onCloseUpdate="imageGrid" and then in the bookmarklet.close method I set shouldRender to false but when the dialog opens again the panel is already rendered. Any ideas?